# Node Module Error When Trying To Deploy Project On Heroku?

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, server, hosting

Not really too sure what the problem is here. I changed my node version in the package.json already, I reinstalled npm after deleting my packae-lock.json as well. Has anyone else ran into this issue and how do I fix this?

````
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code EUSAGE
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's type-fest@0.21.3 does not satisfy type-fest@0.13.1
       npm ERR! Missing: type-fest@0.21.3 from lock file
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Clean install a project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Usage:
       npm ERR! npm ci
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Options:
       npm ERR! [--no-audit] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts]
       npm ERR! [--script-shell <script-shell>]
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.EX2Wa/_logs/2022-07-15T17_34_47_694Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed```
````

Comment: `\`npm ci\` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with \`npm install\` before continuing.`—so... did you update your lock file with `npm install`, commit, and redeploy?

Comment: Have you tried updating your `package-lock.json` first before deploying it again? `npm update package-lock.json`

Answer (score 0):

When you install modules with NPM, it creates two things :

- `package-lock.json` file,
- `node_modules` folder.

The first one contains the name and version of all the dependencies your app needs, and the second contains the actual modules and dependencies specified in the `package-lock.json` file.

Before pushing your app into Heroku, delete the `package-lock.json` (**NOT** `package.json`) file.

Then, reinstall modules via `npm install` command.

It will generate an up to date `package-lock.json`. Then, push your app.